# How to grant users permission to create sprints and backlogs in AzureDevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

How do I grant user permission to create sprints and backlogs without giving project administrator access? This is the type of access that project managers or scrum masters would need. I want to make sure they are unable to make any code contribution, edit build/release pipeline, add/remove users, make changes to project etc.

Answer (score 0):

Make them a contributor and change their [access level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=vsts) to Stakeholder.

Comment: In Azure DevOps 2020 the documentation says this is possible when you are Project Administrator. However, with access level Stakeholder you get a message: You do not have sufficient permissions to configure "iterations".

Source:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/get-started/permissions-access-boards?view=azure-devops-2020

Other Source that confirms my message:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops-2020